# Mockery: mock publicaly overridden protected method

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I have an abstract base class with an abstract protected method

```
abstract class AbstractSample
{
    abstract protected function getConnection();
}
```

and child class where protected method is redefined as public:

```
class ConcreteSample extends AbstractSample
{
    public function getConnection()
    {
        return 'connection resource';
    }
}
```

This is the class I want to test:

```
class Caller
{
    protected $_sample;

    public function __construct(ConcreteSample $sample)
    {
        $this->_sample = $sample;
    }

    public function method()
    {
        $conn = $this->_sample->getConnection();
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

and the test unit itself:

```
class Sample_Test extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_getConnection()
    {
        $RESOURCE = 'mocked resource';
        $mSample = \Mockery::mock(ConcreteSample::class);
        $mSample
            ->shouldReceive('getConnection')->once()
            ->andReturn($RESOURCE);
        $obj = new Caller($mSample);
        $res = $obj->method();
        $this->assertEquals($RESOURCE, $res);
    }
}
```

When I run the test I have an error:

```
InvalidArgumentException : getConnection() cannot be mocked as it a protected method and mocking protected methods is not allowed for this mock
 /.../vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery.php:670
 /.../vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery.php:678
 /.../vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery.php:629
 /.../var/tmp/Sample_Test.php:13
```

How can I mock public method that redefines protected method in the base class? Mockery version is 0.9.4

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/497) in padraic/mockery on github.

Comment: dafuq? an `abstract protected function` can be overwritten by `public function`? I would decline this pull request...

Comment: This is bug in Mockery and it is fixed in the development branch. The last version is 0.9.5 and it is affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$mSample = \Mockery::mock(ConcreteSample::class)
          ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
```